# Pop-up breaks if I add formatted text in it

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend, formatted-text

I created this simple "pop-up" tool, that when you hover on a specific text it displays a definition of that text. Here is how it's done http://jsfiddle.net/D4PzD/ when you hover on "definition link" you'll see it shows a box with some text.

so the basic structure of it is:

```
<span class="title">Title of definition</span>
<span class="def_box">Content that appears on hover here</span>
```

The problem I'm having is that if I add any html markup in the def_box like a list tag `<ul>` or `<p>` the def_box breaks. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FDEKY/

The css:

```
span.title {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #2693e0;
cursor: help;
color: #000;
}
span.def_box {
display: none;
width: 400px;
position: absolute;
height: auto;
left: 25px;
font-size: 17px;
z-index: 400;
line-height: 22px;
border: 2px solid #2693e0;
outline: 5px solid #fff;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 13px 20px;
background: #fff;
}
span.title:hover + span.def_box {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: It is working for me in both ways.

Comment: The list appears outside of the pop-up

Comment: Please post your code if you want help debugging it.

Comment: The code was in the jsfiddle examples I showed you, I thought it was enough, but now I also updated the question with the rest of it.

Comment: When I view the DOM, the `<UL>` is not within `<span class="def_box">

Comment: Lists are not valid content of a `<span>` or `<p>`, so the browser is automatically closing your `<span>` and `<p>` tags, thus forcing your list back into viewable content

Comment: Try making it a DIV instead of a SPAN

Comment: @Barmar Still won't work properly because it will still break the enclosing p, meaning the CSS sibling selector won't select the div.

Comment: if I use a DIV instead of a span, the text that is following the "Title of definition" breaks to a new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it and "fixed" it. Here is how I did it if anyone is curious: http://codepen.io/roxi_t/pen/Fbldu

Comment: To summarise: you put the `<ul>` inside a `<div>` instead of a `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>`s are not allowed inside `<span>`s

Comment: Try running the full html through http://validator.w3.org, and you'll get a message like this:document type does not allow element "UL" here; missing one of "APPLET", "OBJECT", "MAP", "IFRAME", "BUTTON" start-tag